# Why can't postgresql execute select statement whose 'where' clause has a key-matching predicate?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select * from note where noteKey = 1
```

This statement gives me the following error.

```
ERROR:  column "notekey" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from note where noteKey = 1
                                 ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "note.noteKey".
```

I tried note.noteKey, but got the same error. (I used postico by the way, and the noteKey is the primary key of the table note).

What could possibly be wrong with the statement?

Comment: You probably created the column with double quotes using `"noteKey"` which is a different column name then `noteKey` or `notekey`. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: please post your "describe note;"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, is there a way to know if a field has been created with double quotes, other than write a single select query?

Comment: Check the definition of the table, e.g. the `create table` statement you used. or use `\d note` in `psql` or whatever your SQL client supports. I strongly recommend to **never** use double quotes in SQL.

Comment: try select * from note where "noteKey" = 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect with psql and run `\d note`.

If that shows the column is called `noteKey` with an uppercase `K` then you either have two options

1. Rename the column `ALTER TABLE note RENAME COLUMN "noteKey" TO notekey;`
2. Forever use double quotes `"` to query it.

In PostgreSQL we *never* quote column names. This forces them to be caps sensitive. When not quoted, they're automatically lower cased.

This

```
select * from note where noteKey = 1
```

Is the same as

```
select * from note where notekey = 1
```

Which is different from

```
select * from note where "noteKey" = 1
```